# How to do profiling in standard code base?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I did some profiling procedures before. I used

```
from odoo.tools.profiler import profile

@profile
def ...
```

in my customized modules, and then update the module. The profile did show up as intended.

However, now that I am trying to do the same thing but put it in the standard code base of Odoo Community. For example, `write` method in `stock.picking` model. However, the profiler does not show up in the terminal.

```
@profile
def write(self, vals):
```

Is there anything needed to be done for this case? I just want to monitor the performance of some standard methods.

This is how I update and run the Odoo process.

```
python odoo-bin -r xxx -w xxx --addons-path=odoo/addons,odoo/custom_addons -d OdooDB -u stock
```